# get the entry point to a 64bit process memory from a 32bit process

Tags: c++, windows, memory, process, readprocessmemory

I want to get the entry point to a 64bit process I wrote from a 32bit process, the same way you'd use EnumProcessModule and take the memory addr of the main module.
My end goal is to read a byte from memory in my 64bit process from an offset to it (entry+Offset).

But my NtWow64ReadVirtualMemory64 function keeps failing. 
I think it has something to do with my entry memory addr.

```
    #define PROC_BASIC_INFO 0
    #define NT_WOW64_QUERY_INFORMATION_PROCESS_64_NAME  "NtWow64QueryInformationProcess64"
    #define NT_WOW64_READ_VIRTUAL_MEMORY_64_NAME  "NtWow64ReadVirtualMemory64"

    typedef UINT64 SYM;
    typedef SIZE_T SIZE_T64;

    HWND   WINDOW_HANDLE;
    HANDLE PROC_HANDLE;
    DWORD PROC_ID;
    UINT address;
    UINT64 address64;
    SIZE_T bytesRead;
    SIZE_T64 bytesRead64;

    using namespace std;


    //initialize variables for importing of essential 64 bit reading functions
    //from ntdll
    typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI *FUNC_NtReadVirtualMemory64)
    ( 
        IN  HANDLE  ProcessHandle,
        IN  PVOID64 BaseAddress,
        OUT PVOID   Buffer,
        IN  ULONGLONG BufferLength,
        OUT PULONGLONG ReturnLength OPTIONAL
    );
    typedef NTSTATUS (NTAPI *FUNC_NtWow64QueryInformationProcess64) 
    (
        IN  HANDLE ProcessHandle,
        IN  ULONG  ProcessInformationClass,
        OUT PVOID  ProcessInformation64,
        IN  ULONG  Length,
        OUT PULONG ReturnLength OPTIONAL
    );

    struct PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION64 {

        SYM Reserved1;
        SYM PebBaseAddress;
        SYM Reserved2[2];
        SYM UniqueProcessId;
        SYM Reserved3;
        /*
        NTSTATUS ExitStatus;
        ULONG64 PebBaseAddress;
        ULONG64 AffinityMask;
        LONG    BasePriority;
        UINT64  Reserved1;
        ULONG64 UniqueProcessId;
        ULONG64 InheritedFromUniqueProcessId;
        */
    };



    HINSTANCE ntdll = LoadLibrary("ntdll.dll");
    FUNC_NtWow64QueryInformationProcess64 NtWow64QueryInformationProcess64 = (FUNC_NtWow64QueryInformationProcess64)GetProcAddress(ntdll, NT_WOW64_QUERY_INFORMATION_PROCESS_64_NAME);
    FUNC_NtReadVirtualMemory64 NtReadVirtualMemory64 = (FUNC_NtReadVirtualMemory64)GetProcAddress(ntdll, NT_WOW64_READ_VIRTUAL_MEMORY_64_NAME);

    int Init32To64MemoryRead(const char* windowClass, const char* caption, SYM addressOffset)
    {

        DWORD cbNeeded;
        DWORD dwdResult;
        HMODULE mainModule;
        BOOL enumResult;
        ULONG read_length=0;
        HINSTANCE ntdll; 
        PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION64 procInfo;
        ZeroMemory(&procInfo, sizeof(procInfo));



        //Get the window handle
        WINDOW_HANDLE = FindWindow(windowClass, NULL);
        if (WINDOW_HANDLE == NULL)
        {
            //Window was not foud
            return 10;
        }

        //Get the process ID
        dwdResult = GetWindowThreadProcessId(WINDOW_HANDLE, &PROC_ID);

        if (dwdResult == 0)
        {
            //Getting Process ID failed
            return 20;
        }

        //Open the process
        PROC_HANDLE = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, PROC_ID);

        if (PROC_HANDLE == NULL)
        {
            //Process failed to open
            return 30;
        }
        DWORD result;

        //Query Proc Information to get .exe entry point
        result = NtWow64QueryInformationProcess64( PROC_HANDLE, 0, &procInfo, sizeof(procInfo), &read_length);
        if (result != 0)
        {
            cerr << "Query Information Process has failed" << endl;

            return 40;
        }

        address64 =  (procInfo.PebBaseAddress + addressOffset);
        cerr << address64 << endl;

        string number;
        stringstream stristream;

        stristream << address64;
        stristream >> number;

        byte testByte = 0;
        (byte)ReadMemory64<byte>(testByte);

        system("PAUSE");
        return 1;
    }


template <typename _ret_t> _ret_t ReadMemory64(_ret_t& ret)
{

    NTSTATUS result = NtReadVirtualMemory64(PROC_HANDLE, (void*)address64, &ret, 8, NULL);
    ///* Debug # when too lazy for breakpoints
    cerr <<"value: " << ret << endl;
    cerr << "Error Code: " << GetLastError() << endl;
    if (result != 0)
    {
        cerr << "ReadMemory Failed.\r\nAddress: " << address64 << "\r\nSize: " << sizeof(_ret_t) << "\r\nResult: " << result << endl;
        cerr << "NtReadVirtualMemory64 has failed" << endl;
        system("PAUSE");

    } //*/
    return ret;
 };
```

I'd like to know what I am doing wrong.

Edit: 
Upon further inspection, I noticed that NtWow64ReadVirtualMemory, does not store a value in the variable "ret" used as the buffer.

Comment: Seem this guy worked on that topic .. have a look at http://blog.rewolf.pl/blog/?p=319

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into it some more. 
but it seems we're doing the same thing, only he uses asm to gain access to the ntdll function, and also enables x64 ntdll functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran a simple test and figured out that the value of my buffer-"ret" was not changed when inserted to the function *"NtWow64ReadVirtualMemory64"*.
 
The code did compile and run without errors(compile and runtime) except for NtReadMemory64 returning a weird number (there is no documentation available for the ntdll NtWow64 functions, so goolgling it did not yield anything useful).
So i figured I am either providing a faulty buffer or am not reading from a valid memory addr.

since I did initialize the buffer explicitly outside of the function, I figured
that my problem is the latter(not providing a valid memory address).

I was using the following when calling NtReadVirtualMemory

```
NTSTATUS result = NtReadVirtualMemory64(PROC_HANDLE, (void*)address64, &ret, 8, NULL);
```

apparently, when calling NtWow64ReadVirtualMemory64, I cast the addr to a 32 bit void pointer `(void*)address64` , and since address64 is a UINT64-type , the cast truncated the address, and I was trying to read off of a memory segment I wasn't able to read 
I resolved it by changing the cast to `(PVOID64)address64`
which casts it to a native 64bit pointer.

simpler than I thought, but finding it was hell after days of googling and reviewing the code.

**Edit:** 
this didn't cut it since my address is wrong.
 I need to get the ".exe"s' entry point through the location of the process' main module in memory. 
looking at the how to now. 
 
any help is appreciated!